# Stored procedure and table inheritance inserting child first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using EF 6 and trying to convert my existing project to use stored procedures for all insert, updates, and deletes.

I have an existing EDMX that contains an inherited set of tables.

I have a base table Transactions that contains the primary key with the identity insert.

I then have a variety of child tables that set transactions as their base table.  These tables have an Id field that is a primary key on that table and a foreign key to transactions - no identity insert.

This works out of the box with EF.  However, when switching to stored procedures, EF is calling the child sproc first which is failing because of my foreign key constraint as it is trying to insert into the child table with id of 0.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're hoping for as an answer? For what reason are you moving from (i'm assuming) the "normal" based manipulation of your table data to SP based?

Comment: the thought is seamless deploys will be easier with all database operations going through sprocs as it will allow us to push database changes without code.  the answer i'm looking for is why is EF calling the sprocs in the wrong order for inherited tables.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making the stored proc for the child table take all of the data (including the common data to the base table).

This sproc then first inserted into the base table and stored the generated id.  Then inserted into the child table and returned the new id.

Because all tables in the hierarchy need sproc mappings you may be able to get away with making the base table abstract (I couldn't), so instead I created dummy sprocs that don't do anything and mapped the base table to the dummy sproc.